# Dividing entity framework connection string into 2 parts

Tags: .net, entity-framework, web-config, connection-string

I'm trying to set up continuous integration for legacy project. In Web.config, there's Entity Framework connection string:

```
<add name="StuffContext" 
     connectionString="
       metadata=res://*/Stuff.csdl|res://*/Stuff.ssdl|res://*/Stuff.msl;
       provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
       provider connection string=&quot;
         data source=mydbserver;
         initial catalog=mydb;
         persist security info=True;
         user id=loki2302;
         password=qwerty;
         multipleactiveresultsets=True;
         App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
       providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Is there a way to somehow extract `provider connection string` and have it referenced by name in `StuffContext` connection string? Trying to achieve something like this:

```
...
<add name="StuffContext" 
     connectionString="metadata=...;name=StuffDb" />

<add name="StuffDb"
     connectionString="
       data source=mydbserver;
       initial catalog=mydb;
       persist security info=True;
       user id=loki2302;
       password=qwerty;
       multipleactiveresultsets=True;
       App=EntityFramework" />
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in `web.config`, no, but you can certainly do it with [EntityConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738533.aspx).

Comment: I understand what you want, but I'm telling you what is possible.

Comment: One other possible solution, which is not what you are asking for, but might solve your actual problem, is a web.config transformation.